# Latest version of Xmarin.Forms.Maps breaks custom renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Trying to display a circle on a map using Custom Renderer. (Android)

Updated Xamarin.Forms.Maps to v2.3.3.175 and now I am getting error: CustomMapRenderer.OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs)': no suitable method found to override.

Worked previously with no issues. Even the sample from link below no longer works.
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/maps/map-overlay/circle/

Changing `ElementChangedEventArgs<View>` to `ElementChangedEventArgs<Map>` resolves the error but the renderer is never called so the circle is never shown.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

My Custom Android Renderer:

```
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android;
using GasFinder;
using MapOverlay.Droid;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap),typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace MapOverlay.Droid {
    public class CustomMapRenderer:MapRenderer, IOnMapReadyCallback {
    GoogleMap map;
    CustomCircle circle;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e) {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(e.OldElement != null) {
            // Unsubscribe
        }

        if(e.NewElement != null) {
            var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
            circle = formsMap.Circle;
            ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this);
        }
    }
    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;

        var circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
        circleOptions.InvokeCenter(new LatLng(circle.Position.Latitude,circle.Position.Longitude));
        circleOptions.InvokeRadius(circle.Radius);
        circleOptions.InvokeFillColor(0X233273b1);
        circleOptions.InvokeStrokeColor(0X64007eff);
        circleOptions.InvokeStrokeWidth(10);
        map.AddCircle(circleOptions);
    }
}
}
```

CustomMap.cs is as follows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace GasFinder {
    public class CustomMap:Map {
        public CustomCircle Circle { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CustomCircle.cs is as follows:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace GasFinder {
    public class CustomCircle {
        public Position Position { get; set; }
        public double Radius { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Code on my Page.xaml.cs is as follows:

```
var position = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(Search.loc.lat,Search.loc.lng);
customMap.Circle = new CustomCircle {
    Position = position,
    Radius = Settings.Distance*1000
};
```

Comment: The method signature should be `protected override void OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map> e)` (you could leave out some namespaces if you add them in your usings list). Are you sure it is called? Did you put any breakpoints in that get hit?

Comment: That's what I had but that line doesn't work.

Comment: If you type `override` and let IntelliSense suggest you? What does it come up with?

Comment: Hi @RussellCorbin Did you end up solving this? Currently facing the same issue

Comment: Yes I did. I will post code shortly.

Comment: `code` protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e) {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(e.OldElement != null) {
            }

            if(e.NewElement != null) {
                var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
                circle = formsMap.Circle;
                ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this);
            }
        }

Comment: I'm sure I did try this before and it did not work so ensure you've updated the Nuget packages to Xamarin.Forms.Maps v2.3.3.193

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Xamarin.Forms.Maps v2.3.3.193

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e) {
    base.OnElementChanged(e); 
    if(e.OldElement != null) { } 
    if(e.NewElement != null) { 
        var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement; 
        circle = formsMap.Circle; 
        ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this); 
    } 
}
```